# interaction of pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to understand exactly how `numpy` and `pandas` interact. In particular, a `pandas.Series` object is an `ndarray` with labels according to the docstring. `numpy` methods seem to work just fine on these types of objects.. is there casting somewhere under the hood? The best I have been able to dig up is that `numpy.asanyarray()` is called to convert the `pandas.Series` to an `ndarray` in some of the `numpy` functions. Is there anything else happening internally?

Comment: May want to google [BlockManager](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#removal-of-blockmanager--new-dataframe-internals).  This is the `._data` attribute of Pandas objects that does most of the actual "wrapping" around NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `pandas` containers are not `numpy.ndarray` objects, strictly speaking. That is, they do not inherit from them. IOW:

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [7]: s = pd.Series()

In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: isinstance(df, np.ndarray)
Out[9]: False

In [10]: isinstance(s, np.ndarray)
Out[10]: False
```

Or, stated more directly:

```
In [12]: issubclass(pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray), issubclass(pd.Series, np.ndarray)
Out[12]: (False, False)
```

Simply put, these containers *wrap* `numpy.ndarray` objects, and expose many of the same methods. There is no casting going on. Casting is not a very useful concept in a language that uses duck-typing like Python.